# convert cheerio.load() to a DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to learn how to make a web scraper and save content from a site into a text file using node. My issue is that to get the content, I am using cheerio and jquery (I think?), which I have no experience with. I'm trying to take the result I got from cheerio and convert it to a DOM object which I have much more experience dealing with. How can I take the html from cheerio and convert it to a DOM object? Thanks in advance!

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/overgeared/og-chapter-153',(error, response, html) => {
if(!error & response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log(html);
    html.getElementsByClassName('fr-view')[1];//I want the ability to do this

}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), the first example there shows u how to add a class and get a string with the HTML.

You can change your code to look like that:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://www.wuxiaworld.com/novel/overgeared/og-chapter-153',(error, response, html) => {
  if(!error & response.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const result = $('.my-calssName').html(); // cheerio api to find by css selector, just like jQuery.
      console.log(result);
  }
})
```

Comment: I was just using that as an example, my point is I want to use the result as a DOM object

Comment: String? or DOM, As far as I know, there is no real DOM in node (without jsdom), cheerio gives you a jquery like api to manipulate html structure.